# How can I create SerachParameter based on resource’s resource on FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have **Basic** object with **the subject** that referenced to **ImagingStudy**.
ImagingStudy with **the subject** that referenced to **Patient** object.

I want to create SearchParameter on **Basic** object that filtering and sorting by Patient attributes ( name, gender etc.)

I can create SearchParameter for ImagingStudy on Basic. It works.
But multi deep (Basic->ImagingStudy->Patient) is not working.

Do you have any idea about this?

thanks,
best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to servers whether they support chaining and what level of chaining they support.  It's possible for a server to support custom search parameters (e.g. your new ImagingStudy.subject) search parameter without necessarily supporting chaining through that parameter.  You'll need to reach out to whoever developed the server you're using.